# (New) "Update" button in Custom Translator models

Tags: microsoft-translator

Since a few days ago, I noticed a new button “Update” in my deployed custom models. I don’t recall having seen this documented anywhere or having received any notification about this new functionality. Can anyone explain what exactly this new button does?

Answer (score 0):

The change of the Undeploy button to an Update button was made in order to better indicate that, once deployed, you can update the deployment settings of your deployed model rather than just undeploying the model.  If you press update, you are now presented with a list of regions you can deploy to or undeploy from.  Setting all regions to undeployed is the equivalent of undeploying the model.